# Request header field <field-name> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, mean

I have a React app that is trying to make an axios request to my Express server to find a user in a Mongo database. Before, I built the back-end on Rails and had a gem for CORS, and after trying to configure CORS on the Express side, I can't seem to find a solution. I want to be able to pass in a custom field in headers (i.e. username) so I can use that field to query against my database.

Error I get in browser:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/users/test. 
Request header field username is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
in preflight response.
```

My Express server has the following CORS set up and my React axios code is attempting to make a request to the server with a param passed into the headers objects, but still getting preflight in response error.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
    Origin, 
    Accept, 
    X-Requested-With, 
    Content-Type, 
    Access-Control-Request-Method, 
    Access-Control-Request-Headers, 
    Authorization")
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});

export const loadAccount = (username) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    axios
    .get(`${url}/users/test`, {
      headers: {username: username}
    })
    .then(resp => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOAD_ACCOUNT',
        account: resp.data
      })
    })
    .catch(errors => {
      console.log(errors)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44250594/edit to edit/update your question and paste in the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like you have to add `username` as a valid header in your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` clause, i.e.:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
  Origin, 
  Accept, 
  X-Requested-With, 
  Content-Type, 
  Access-Control-Request-Method, 
  Access-Control-Request-Headers, 
  Authorization,
  username")
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
next();
```

Comment: That did the trick! I do wonder then, in a situation where my project ever gets large enough and I'll need to pass many custom headers to the Headers clause, then that clause could potentially get large. Is there a workaround or a catch-all that one can declare in the clause to catch any/all custom headers?

Comment: you should be able to just use `*` or remove the header altogether, I believe the default is to allow anything but I'm not 100% sure